# How to prove / deduce that moment of this expression is equal to moments of normal random variable.

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory

Consider the following paragraph in notes of number theory:<sup>1</sup>

[image]

Can you please explain what are moments of $\frac{ \omega(n) -\log \log x}{ \sqrt{\log \log x}}$?

and how they become equal to moments of normal random variable.

I am really confused about it.

<sup>1</sup>Steve Lester: [Normal order of $\omega(n)$ and the Erdös-Kac theorem](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015/ErdosKac.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170309092146/http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015/ErdosKac.pdf))

Comment: Is that screenshot taken from Steve Lester: [Normal order of $\omega(n)$ and the Erdös-Kac theorem](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015/ErdosKac.pdf)? I think including the source would be useful for others (potential answerers and also other people interested in this question).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes it's taken from those notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x\in\mathbb{N}$, and consider the random variable $N$, uniform on $\{1,2,\dots,x\}$. Now, define the (new) random variable
$$
f(N) = \frac{\omega(N)-\log\log x}{\sqrt{\log\log x}}
$$
The moments of $f(N)$ are just
$
\mathbb{E}[f(N)]
$, $
\mathbb{E}[f(N)^2]
$, etc., the $k$-th moment being
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(N)^k] = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} f(n)^k \Pr[N=n]
= \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^x f(n)^k= \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{(\omega(N)-\log\log x)^k}{(\log\log x)^{k/2}}
$$
(using the [law of the unsconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician));
and, from the asymptotics given in the text you give, this is
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(N)^k] = m_k + o(1)
$$
i.e., *"the moments of $\frac{\omega(N)-\log\log x}{\sqrt{\log\log x}}$ [for $N$ uniform on $\{1,\dots,x\}$] are asymptotically equal to those of a standard normal r.v."*